# Sortable js library not working as expected inside iframe in safari

Tags: javascript, rubaxa-sortable

When sortable library is used inside a iframe in safari, the draggable element is not working as expected as in other browsers.

HTML:

```
<iframe src="http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/" width="1000" height="1000"></iframe>
```

Javascript:

```
Sortable.create(foo, {
  group: 'foo',
  animation: 100
});

Sortable.create(bar, {
  group: 'bar',
  animation: 100
});

Sortable.create(qux, {
  group: {
    name: 'qux',
    put: ['foo', 'bar']
  },
  animation: 100
});
```

If you open this in Safari browser, the element which is dragged is far away from the cursor pointer.

Is there any workaround?

[Demo URL](http://jsbin.com/kigopu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Could you post the code in the question itself? Wonder why the interface requires code with JSFiddle...

Comment: Not using any custom code. Its the same demo example given in github. Just wrapped the url in an iframe

Comment: Please put relevant code in your question and check your question for spelling mistakes and correct use of <code> and <pre>.